# OpenCart 3 - PayPal Express - payment: function - add additional custom function

Tags: javascript, paypal

In a paypal express script, I need to change this to make an ajax call to post a form that will return the paypal token.

In the below script, assuming {{ continue }} returned `{"token":"EC-RANDOMSTRING"}`

Then

payment:EC-RANDOMSTRING

```js
        payment: function (data, actions) {
          return paypal.request.get("{{ continue }}", {
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/paypal-json-token',
            }
          }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response || !response.token) {
              throw new Error('There was an error fetching the PayPal token');
            }

            return response.token;
          }).catch(function (err) {
            throw err;
          });
        },
```

So If I had an external ajax call named myFormPost() which returned `{"token":"EC-RANDOMSTRING"}` would the following be correct:

```js
var response = myFormPost();                
payment: response.token,
```

Am I correct thinking that the value for payment: can come from anywhere as long as it is a valid PayPal Token?

Answer (score 0):

For others using OpenCart who may come across this.

The default script in \catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\payment\pp_express.twig is

```js
    (function () {
      paypal.Button.render({
        env: '{{ paypal_environment }}',
        style: {
          layout: '{{ payment_pp_express_style_layout }}',
          size:   '{{ payment_pp_express_style_size }}',
          shape:  '{{ payment_pp_express_style_shape }}',
          color:  '{{ payment_pp_express_style_color }}'
        },
        commit: true,
        funding: {
          allowed: [{{ allowed_payment_methods }}],
          disallowed: [{{ disallowed_payment_methods }}]
        },  
        payment: function (data, actions) {
          return paypal.request.get("{{ continue }}", {
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/paypal-json-token',
            }
          }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response || !response.token) {
              throw new Error('There was an error fetching the PayPal token');
            }

            return response.token;
          }).catch(function (err) {
            throw err;
          });
        },
        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.redirect();
        },
        onCancel: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.redirect();
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          $('.pp-checkout-button-container').empty().html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
          return;
        }
      }, '#pp-checkout-button');
    })();
```

Replace the default payment method in the script with a call to your external script

```js
    (function () {
      paypal.Button.render({
        env: '{{ paypal_environment }}',
        style: {
          layout: '{{ payment_pp_express_style_layout }}',
          size:   '{{ payment_pp_express_style_size }}',
          shape:  '{{ payment_pp_express_style_shape }}',
          color:  '{{ payment_pp_express_style_color }}'
        },
        commit: true,
        funding: {
          allowed: [{{ allowed_payment_methods }}],
          disallowed: [{{ disallowed_payment_methods }}]
        },
  payment: function(){
   var response = myCustomValidationFunction();
   return response.token;
  },
        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.redirect();
        },
        onCancel: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.redirect();
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          $('.pp-checkout-button-container').empty().html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
          return;
        }
      }, '#pp-checkout-button');
    })();
```

```js
function myCustomValidationFunction(){
 /* External function for paypal.Button.render  */
 /* must return json data with a toekn element */
 var json;
 json.token = $.get(stript that returns json with token);
 return json;
}
```